# Problems with exposing Kafka to outside network on Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka

It is still a mystery to me how to expose Kafka to external network. I deployed Kafka on google cloud virtual machine using "Kafka certified by Bitnami", which runs Kafka 2.3.0 and Zookeeper 3.5.5. I opened firewall on ports `9092, 2181` (yes I can telnet it) and assigned static IP address to my machine. My server.properties file looks like this:

```
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://<static_ip>:9092
zookeeper.connect=localhost:9092
```

I tried to connect from Python:

```
from kafka.admin import KafkaAdminClient
import logging 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG) 

admin_client = KafkaAdminClient(
    bootstrap_servers="<static_ip>:9092", 
    client_id='test',
    sasl_plain_username="bitnami_provided_user",
    sasl_plain_password="bitnami_provided_password"
)
```

What I get is this Error: `Closing connection. KafkaConnectionError: socket disconnected`.

I also changed `SASL_PLAINTEXT` to `PLAINTEXT` and then I get `NoBrokersAvailable` Error.

I went through this thread [Not able to connect to kafka server on google compute engine from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811824/not-able-to-connect-to-kafka-server-on-google-compute-engine-from-local-machine) and tried to make the same, but without luck. Is this really so difficult to expose Kafka to external network? I just want to access it from home and my local computer.

Comment: I have just deployed different image from marketplace with kafka 2.1.1 and it works. Just changed `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<static_ip>:9092` and left `listeners` commented. Still do not know why my first approach didn't work