# connecting spark streaming from local machine to kafka on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I currently have 4 VMs on GCP. 1 is where my zookeeper is hosted and the other 3 are kafka-brokers named kafka-0,kafka-1,kafka-2. Everything works fine when producing/consuming messages within the VMS, but it begins to fail when I try to connect to Kafka from my local machine. Firstly I opened firewall rules for port 9092(on all instances). I then added a static external IP each instance. I am trying to connect to my kafka broker from a local spark streaming job.

Just for sanity checks, my zookeeper is able to connect to all the brokers

i.ie This bash command ran on my zookeeper (10.150.0.6:2181 is the internal IP for zookeeper)

```
zookeeper-shell.sh 10.150.0.6:2181 ls /brokers/ids
```

gives me the following output

```
Connecting to 10.150.0.6:2181
WATCHER::
WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[0, 1, 2]
```

**My first approach**. I tried to connect to one of the kafka brokers using the broker's external IP

```
val df = sparkSession.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",
        "34.86.170.127:9092")
      .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME_CONS)
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
      .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
      .load()
```

This gave me the following error

```
 java.net.UnknownHostException: kafka-0.us-west2-c.c.civic-animal-213016.internal: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I find this error interesting because it somehow figures out the name of my host on GCP even when I only give it.(this can be confirmed from `zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 <<< "get /brokers/ids/0`")

So I researched the problem further and came upon this blog post.
https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/ and learned about advertised listeners. And then I read the following stackoverflow exchange.

[Not able to connect to kafka server on google compute engine from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811824/not-able-to-connect-to-kafka-server-on-google-compute-engine-from-local-machine)

**Second Approach**

I tried the answer out. So I VMed into my kafka-0 broker instance and ran the following command

```
vi kafka_2.12-2.0.0/config/server.properties
```

And then I uncommented out advertised listeners and changed

```
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

to

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://[instance_public_id_address]:9092
```

So this resolved to

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka-0.us-west2-c.c.civic-animal-213016.internal:9092
```

However, this still gives me the same error

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: kafka-0.us-west2-c.c.civic-animal-213016.internal: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

So *Attempt 3*, I tried changing instead of connecting using the external IP, I could use the host name instead like

```
val df = sparkSession.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",
        "kafka-0.us-west2-c.c.civic-animal-213016.internal:9092")
      .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME_CONS)
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
      .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
      .load()
```

but I get the following error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
```

I'm confused about how to solve this? Any steps to help me go further

Comment: `.internal` is what it says it is. I don't think that is your "Public DNS" name

Comment: when I run zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 <<< "get /brokers/ids/1". I get folowing infromation about the broker

Comment: That is the same information that you put in `advertised.listeners`

Comment: So, it appears that `34.86.170.127:9092` worked correctly... You opened the port, and the bootstrap request was sent through. Then, the internal addresses were returned back (via Zookeeper), but those hostnames cannot be resolved outside your VPC

Comment: Also, it's best to use multiple listeners. One for the internal traffic, then another for external network clients (its also not a good idea to open PLAINTEXT protocol outside your network, but thats a separate issue)

Comment: right I followed the DNS name from https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns
It seems the name I put is correct, but again why can't the hostname not be resolved? I set the firewall rules for 9092 in all instances. If I ping the external IP address it responds. However, if I ping kafka-0.us-west2-c.c.civic-animal-213016.internal, then there is no response

Comment: "internal DNS" is not the same as public DNS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out I was confused on what to put in for advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://[instance_public_id_address]:9092

I changed

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka-0.us-west2-c.c.civic-animal-213016.internal:9092
```

to this

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://34.86.170.127:9092
```

where 34.86.170.127:9092 is my external IP on the VM instance.